# How do I use document.cookie to store and retrieve the values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

I am storing and retrieving values in cookies using methods:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
};
```

and

```
function getCookie() {
    var name = "name=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
};
```

Now I need to store/retrieve arrays in a similar fashion. I know I'll need to create the array as a single string and then parse it back but what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend using [JSON](http://www.json.org/). First, you convert the array into a JSON string:

```
var array = ["one","two","three"];
var json_string = JSON.stringify(array);
```

Then you set the cookie with the JSON string as the value.

```
setCookie("array", json_string, exdays);
```

Then when you retrieve the JSON string from the cookie later, convert it back into an actual array.

```
var json_string = getCookie("array");
var array = JSON.parse(json_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you want to store/retrieve multiple cookies.Your get Cookie thing nearly does it:

```
function getCookies() {
var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
return ca.map(function(c){
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
    }
        return c.split("=");
    }
});
};
```

You just have to return all, not the first, and you need to remove the namedetection.

```
console.log(getCookies());
```

SetCookies:

```
function setCookies(Cookies,exp){
 Cookies.forEach(function(el){setCookie(el[0],el[1],exp);});
}

setCookies([
  ["name","value"]
 ]);
```